# Discord.js I am not able to create a role with specific permission which is a mute role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "Use this to mute members",

    execute: async function (msg, arg) {
        const muterole = await msg.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "Mute");
        let promise = new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            if (muterole) {
                resolve(commandmute(msg, arg));
            } else {
                reject(createrole(msg, arg));
            }
        });

        async function createrole(msg, arg) {
            msg.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                    name: "Mute",
                },
                reason: "This is a mute role created by the bot ",
            });
            const tole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "Mute");
            const ch1 = msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach((ch, msg) => {
                if ((ch = msg.guild.channels.type("text"))) {
                    ch.updateOverwrite(tole, { VIEW_MESSAGES: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true });
                }

                msg.reply("It seems that the server doesnt have a Mute role so the bot has created one ");
                msg.reply("Successfully created the role");
            });
        }

        function commandmute(msg, arg) {}
    },
};
```

So I am using a promise to check whether the server has a mute role or not, and if it doesn't it will pass over to a function that will create a role named 'Mute'.

Now the problem is that I am not able to figure out how to change the permissions of the role in a channel so that users with the aforementioned role cannot send messages.

Also, I am not able to get the id of the role by doing role.id.
It shows undefined.

Comment: I didn’t see you define `role` anywhere. Where was it?

Answer (score 0):

If role.id shows undefined, it must be because your "tole" const is undefined too. I recommand you trying this :

```
async function createrole(msg, arg) {
            msg.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                    name: "Mute",
                },
                reason: "This is a mute role created by the bot ",
            }).then( role => {
              msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach((ch, msg) => {
                if (ch = msg.guild.channels.type("text")) {
                  ch.updateOverwrite(role, { VIEW_MESSAGES: true, SEND_MESSAGES: false });
                }
              }
            });

            msg.reply("It seems that the server doesnt have a Mute role so the bot has created one ");
            msg.reply("Successfully created the role");
            
        }
```

By using `then()`, you make sure the role is created, and you can directly get the role object and use it, instead of using `msg.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "Mute")`.